# Updated from 12.04 to 14.04, software center now saying I have no permission to download software

Tags: permissions, software-center, chromebook

just a note I'm not an expert at this.  I'm using crouton linux with xfce and recently updated from 12.04 to 14.04.  I'd done this with my previous crouton-installed chromebook fine, but now I can't install anything from the software center.  Help?

Comment: What are you trying to download? what error messages are you getting?

Comment: Please run `software-center` in a terminal window (CTRL+ALT+T), use it until the permissions error gets displayed again, then close it and copy&paste the terminal output (which hopefully contains some nice error messages) to your question ([edit] it, don't post command outputs as comment!). Thanks.

Comment: @ByteCommander: good one! (posting here so I will see the updates)

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, then run the following commands:

1. Remove the software center and all its packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge software-center
   ```
2. Remove on hold packages (saved in temp)

   ```
   sudo apt-get autoclean
   ```
3. Update Ubuntu packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Re-install the software center

   ```
   sudo apt-get install software-center
   ```
5. Update all application:

   ```
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```

And then run the software center and check for errors:

```
 software-center
```

Comment: Don't think this will help... And the next time, you should use better formatting and write a bit more text around your commands.

Comment: This is not an answer as it doesn't explain why the OP needs to type those commands, nor what they will accomplish.  Please [edit] your question and improve it, drop me a comment @Fabby and I'll come back and upvote instead of the downvote you now have...

Comment: Much better.  In the future: [use 4/8/12 spaces](http://askubuntu.com/posts/706687/revisions) to get correct indentation of code (depending on sub-level)  **;-)**